# Listitem to have design of 'btn-primary' in Bootstrap framework?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug

I have the following list items in my navigation bar. I would like to make  'sign up' to have the same design as a btn-primary (this is pug). How can I do that?

```
 ul.nav.navbar-nav
    li
      a(href="#") Product
    li
      a(href="#") Features
    li
      a(href="#") Pricing
    li
      a(href="#") Blog
    li
      a(href="#") Contact Us
  ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
    li
      a(href="sign-up") Sign Up
    li
      a(href="sign-in") Login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this one. Hope this helps you.

```
     ul.nav.navbar-nav
        li
          a(href="#") Product
        li
          a(href="#") Features
        li
          a(href="#") Pricing
        li
          a(href="#") Blog
        li
          a(href="#") Contact Us
     ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
        li
          a.btn.btn-primary(href="sign-up") Sign Up
        li
          a(href="sign-in") Login
```

You could convert HTML to Pug on [HTML2Pug](http://html2pug.com/) as well. It is a nice Website for beginner to learn Pug.